# Null Pointer Exception in my BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to search a db and toast a specific column on the startup of the phone. The app keeps crashing and getting an exception even though I feel as the code is correct.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("omg", "1");
    DBAdapter do = new DBAdapter(ctx);
    Log.d("omg", "2");
    Cursor cursor = do.fetchAllItems();
    Log.d("omg", "3");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("omg", "4");
        do {
            Log.d("omg", "5");
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item"));
            Log.d("omg", "6");
            // i = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            Toast.makeText(ctx, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

The frustrating part is that I don't see any of my "omg" logs show up in logcat. I only see when my application crashes.

I get three lines of errors in logcat.

```
10-19 12:31:11.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.test.toaster.MyReciever: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 12:31:11.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at com.test.toaster.DBAdapter.fetchAllItems(DBAdapter.java:96)
10-19 12:31:11.656: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at com.test.toaster.MyReciever.onReceive(MyReciever.java:26)
```

For anyone interested, here is my DBAdapter fetchAllItems code:

```
public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ITEM, KEY_PRIORITY,
            KEY_ROWID }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Is `mDb` initialized properly?

Comment: Can you show us where your registering your receiver? NullPointer exception usually means your not registering it right.

Comment: Liking the `omg` logs lol. Reminds of back in school when we used to use `cout` debugging with lots of _very_ colorful comments =P

Comment: You should be looking at `DBAdapter.fetchAllItems` , line number 96 to see what could be possible null object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `mDb` is `null` in `fetchAllItems()`, you need to initialize `mDb` before trying to use it.

This just a guess but many DBAdapter designs have an `open()` method, does yours? If so, you simply need to call it before calling `fetchAllItems()`. If not, you still need to call `mDb = ...` somewhere in your adapter.

Comment: I put `do.open();` and `do.close();` and I think it worked (no errors, but seem to have the wrong db entries toasting there). What do you mean "mDb = ..."?

Comment: The phrase "initialize `mDb`" often confuses people, it simply means setting `mDB` to _some value_, hence `mDb = ...`. I find that describing it both ways helps most people understand.